# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (using an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm have an array set-up that will pass two arguments into the function. However, when I use console.log I get an exception. It's strange because if I were to remove the arguments from the parameters, it will run, is their any reason for this and how do I fix it?

```
var musicians = ["Paul", "John", "Yuri"];

var instruments = ["Drums", "Guitar", "Chelo"];

function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {

    var empty = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < **musicians.length**; i++) {

      var str = musicians[i] + " plays " + instruments[i];
      empty = str;
      **console.log(empty)**;
    }
    }

    theBeatlesPlay();
```

Comment: you didn't pass any arguments to the method being invoked.

Comment: Debug your program. Place a breakpoint at the `for` statement. When you  stop there, examine the value of `musicians`. Then think real hard.

Comment: A linter will provide clues. For instance, it is likely to report that `musicians` and `instruments` are declared but never used. Some might also report that the function parameter **shadow** variables used in outer scopes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the arguments to the function, while calling it.

`theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);`

```js
var musicians = ["Paul", "John", "Yuri"],
    instruments = ["Drums", "Guitar", "Chelo"];

function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {
  var empty = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {
    var str = musicians[i] + " plays " + instruments[i];
    empty = str;
    console.log(empty);
  }
}

theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not passing the arguments to the function.
The correct way to use a function is first, the code that calls the function, and then the function. If you use more functions, you will lose track of what you are doing or worse will start to get errors,

```js
var musicians = ["Paul", "John", "Yuri"];

var instruments = ["Drums", "Guitar", "Chelo"];

var errlog = theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);

console.log(errlog);

function theBeatlesPlay(musicians_val, instruments_val) {

var empty = [];

for (var i = 0; i < musicians_val.length; i++) {

var str = musicians_val[i] + " plays " + instruments_val[i];
      empty = str;
     
    }
    return empty;
 }
```

Comment: Always better to explain what the problem was, and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: When you declare a function with parameters, these parameters become local ones. This means that even if you have some variables with names `musicians` and `instruments`, parameters with the same names within a function will still be treated as **local**

To resolve your issue you have two ways:

1. Remove parameters in the function declaration statement (it turns out you want to access those variables which are declared outside of the function, so you don't need parameters for your function):

   ```
   var musicians = ["Paul", "John", "Yuri"],
       instruments = ["Drums", "Guitar", "Chelo"];


   /* Precondition: defined musicians and instruments arrays outside of a function */
   function theBeatlesPlay(/* No params */) {

       var empty = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {

           var str = musicians[i] + " plays " + instruments[i];
           empty = str;
           console.log(empty);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Invoke the function passing to it two arrays declared previously:

   ```
   /* 
       musicians and instruments variables are LOCAL for the function in this case
   */
   function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {

       var empty = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {

           var str = musicians[i] + " plays " + instruments[i];
           empty = str;
           console.log(empty);
       }
   }

   theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);
   ```

I'd also strongly recommend you not to name variables like `empty` becuase it's empty initially. Otherwise it should be a constant.

By the way, it's useful to analyze what type of exception is thrown and what message it provides.